# Subtracting timestamp in oracle returning weird data

Tags: oracle, timestamp, subtraction

I'm trying to subtract two dates and expecting some floating values return. But what I got in return is as below:

```
+000000000 00:00:07.225000
```

Multiplying the value by 86400 (I want to get the difference in second) is getting something even more strange value being returned:

```
+000000007 05:24:00.000000000
```

any idea? I'm suspecting is has something to do with type casting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess your columns are defined as `timestamp` rather than `date`.

The result of subtracting timestamps is an `interval` whereas the result of subtracting `date` columns is a number representing the number of days between the two dates.

This is documented in the manual: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#i48042

So when you cast your timestamp columns to date, you should get what you expect:

```
with dates as (
   select timestamp '2012-04-27 09:00:00' as col1,
          timestamp '2012-04-26 17:35:00' as col2
   from dual
)
select col1 - col2 as ts_difference,
       cast(col1 as date) - cast(col2 as date) as dt_difference
from dates;
```

**Edit**:

If you want to convert the interval so e.g. the number of seconds (as a number), you can do something like this:

```
with dates as (
   select timestamp '2012-04-27 09:00:00.1234' as col1,
          timestamp '2012-04-26 17:35:00.5432' as col2
   from dual
)
select col1 - col2 as ts_difference,
       extract(hour from (col1 - col2)) * 3600 +  
       extract(minute from (col1 - col2)) * 60 + 
       (extract(second from (col1 - col2)) * 1000) / 1000 as seconds
from dates;
```

The result of the above is `55499.5802`

Comment: the returning result after casting is rounded up to second. is there any better way I can get the difference between two timestamp in floating point value (up to mili or micro second)?

Comment: @YouQi: as what datatypes are those columns defined?

Comment: it's `TIMESTAMP(6)`. I actually query it like this: `((CAST(Res.RAW_DATE AS DATE) - CAST(Req.RAW_DATE AS DATE))*86400) AS TIME_DIFF,`

Comment: @YouQi: the cast to `DATE` "rounds up" to seconds. You are losing the microseconds that way.

Comment: how can I get the return value from db by subtracting two timestamp in SS.ffffff format? example: 2012-04-30 14:52:34.571245 - 2012-04-30 14:49:11.128532 = 203.442715

Answer (score 0):

Read this article:
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551242712657900129

Example:

```
create table yourtable(
date1 date, 
date2 date
)
SQL> select datediff( 'ss', date1, date2 ) seconds from yourtable

   SECONDS 
---------- 
   6269539
```

Comment: is there any way without creating a function? as I do not own the privilege

Comment: you don't need a function, only this statement: select datediff( 'ss', date1, date2 ) seconds from yourtable

Comment: @buzznfrog - Tom creates `datediff` in that article, it isn't a standard built-in function. It also won't work for `timestamp` values as it relies on `date` arithmetic anyway.