# timestamp having milliseconds convert to seconds in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I captured request and response time for procedure i need to calculate time take by substract both request -response  to find time taken.

```
 P_REQUEST_TIME  :='20/MAR/2014 03:03:50.785662 PM';
 P_RESPONSE_TIME :='20/MAR/2014 03:03:50.785816 PM';


 SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(P_REQUEST_TIME)-TO_TIMESTAMP(P_RESPONSE_TIME) 
 into l_actual_time
 FROM dual;
```

Getting result is `Result:='-000000000 00:00:00.000154000';`

I need this as seconds.

Comment: Do you want it rounded up or down? So your output should be a simple 0 or a simple 1?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348140/subtracting-timestamp-in-oracle-returning-weird-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [EXTRACT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) function.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(P_REQUEST_TIME)-TO_TIMESTAMP(P_RESPONSE_TIME)) diff_seconds
FROM <table_name>;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  select extract( day from diff ) days,
      extract( hour from diff ) hours,
      extract( minute from diff ) minutes,
      extract( second from diff ) seconds
  from (SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(REQUEST_DTTM)-TO_TIMESTAMP(RESPONS_DTTM) diff FROM hit_tracer);
```

Answer (score 0):

if u want the difference between two timestamps in seconds, this is the query

```
SELECT (P_REQUEST_TIME-P_RESPONSE_TIME) *24 *60*60
     into l_actual_time
     FROM dual;
```

Comment: your query given result like this   (REQUEST_DTTM-RESPONS_DTTM)*24*60*60
------------------------------------
-0 0:0:8.7264                        
-0 0:0:9.504                         
-0 0:0:13.3056